# Merge results from two "find" commands

Tags: linux, find

I'd like to find all directories that contain *both* a `Makefile` and a file matching `*.tex`.  The command `find` or `locate` easily finds one or the other.  But how can those results be merged or intersected, to yield just the directories desired?

A useful answer generalizes to other filenames.  Even better, it can merge more than two such queries.

(I don't see how to apply `find`'s boolean operators, e.g. "and" `expr1 -a expr2`.  Ditto for `locate -A`.  Maybe two searches, strip the filenames and keep the paths, `sort -u`, into `comm -12 <(cmd1) <(cmd2)`?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `-a` to 'AND' conditions:

```
find . -type d -exec test -f {}/Makefile \; -a -exec bash -c 'compgen -G '{}'/*.tex >/dev/null;exit $?' \; -print
```

In slow-mo:

- `-exec test -f {}/Makefile \;` checks if `Makefile` exists in the directory
- `-exec bash -c 'compgen -G '{}'/*.tex >/dev/null;exit $?'` checks if there are any `*.tex` files in the directory
- the whole line tests true only if both test are true
- in that case print the directory name

Ran on:

```
./no1
./no1/yes3
./no1/yes3/foo.tex
./no1/yes3/Makefile
./no1/no3
./no1/no
./no1/Makefile
./q
./no2
./no2/foo.tex
./yes1
./yes1/foo.tex
./yes1/Makefile
./yes2
./yes2/foo.tex
./yes2/Makefile
```

Gives:

```
./no1/yes3
./yes1
./yes2
```

Comment: +1. I never knew you could use `-exec` as a test; `man find` lists tests and actions separately and `-exec` is under "actions" there. Your answer is a learning material to me.

Comment: Also for me... never used `compgen` before.

Comment: This answer is not perfect by itself (e.g. it doesn't mention that `-a` connects tests by default, you may omit it) *but* what I learnt from it turned out to be so powerful (custom tests like [this](https://superuser.com/a/1221882/432690), yay!) I decided to award it. Keep up the good work.

Comment: And when I started using Unix I thought find was an over complicated command :)

Comment: When I learnt from this answer, I was not aware of this: [never embed `{}` in the shell code](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156010/108618).

Answer (score 1):

`find` can't do "sub-queries" to print directories which contain some files, so `comm` is indeed the way to go:

```
comm -12 <(find . -name Makefile -exec dirname {} \; | sort ) <(find . -name '*.tex' -exec dirname {} \; | sort)
```

You could also loop over directories (recursively with [`globstar`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#globstar_.28since_bash_4.0-alpha.29)) which might be faster ([`compgen` source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34195247)):

```
for directory in */
do
    if [ -e "${directory}/Makefile" ] && compgen -G "${directory}/"*.tex > /dev/null
    then
        printf '%s\n' "${directory}"
    fi
done
```

Comment: This answer is easier to understand and to remember, but xenoid's is single-pass so it's faster on a big filesystem.  (`locate` would be far faster!)