# Linux: How to list all video files with exactly 720p resolution?

Tags: linux, command-line, video, resolution, find

I have several video files with different resolutions. Now I want to list only the video filenames with e.g. 720p resolution. I prefer one liners on the bash command line and I can receive helpful video informations including resolution when I execute:

```
avconv -i video.mp4
```

but this combination:

```
find -exec sh -c 'if [[ "$(avconv -i {}") == *720* ]] ; then echo 720 found; fi;'
```

produces the error: exec - missing argument.

I'm honest, I have hardly fights with bash command structures, especially combined commands.
So, what is wrong in my combined command string?

Thank you.

Comment: This information you need is returned by `ffprobe video.mp4`. It doesn't throw an error while `avconv` does.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this command accommplishes what you are looking for:

```
for i in *.mp4; do if [[ $(avconv -i $i) =~ .*720.* ]]; then echo $i; fi; done
```

Comment: This was a step forward. After I inserted "; done" after "fi", it worked, but with many, many output lines from "avconv". I want to surpress these lines. I only want to receive the matching files and then list the name of the file.

Comment: You are right. I forgot the `done`. Just edited it.

Comment: If you want to output the name of the file you can just do `echo $i` instead of `echo 720 found`.

Comment: I don't have the avconv program installed so I can't test it. But I guess there might be some options to avoid debug or extra output you don't want from that program. Try `man avconv` or `apropos avconv` for help on that program.

Comment: From http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/avconv.1.html I found there is -loglevel options

Answer (score 2):

It may be surprising but `-exec` can be used as a test in `find` invocation:

```
find -type f -exec sh -c 'ffprobe -show_streams 2>/dev/null "$1" | grep -q coded_height=720' sh {} \; -print
```

The above command will descend to subdirectories. To search in the current directory only use `-maxdepth 1`, i.e.:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec …
```

Note that `ffprobe` will test all files. It will obviously fail for non-media files but you may get non-video media (like `.jpg`) in the final output. To avoid this, some additional tests in `find` should be used before `-exec`, e.g.:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f \( -iname "*.avi" -o -iname "*.mp4" -o -iname "*.mkv" \) -exec sh -c 'ffprobe -show_streams 2>/dev/null "$1" | grep -q coded_height=720' sh {} \; -print
```

Or better you can test mime type with `file`:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -exec sh -c 'file --mime-type "$1" | grep -q "video/"' sh {} \; -exec sh -c 'ffprobe -show_streams 2>/dev/null "$1" | grep -q coded_height=720' sh {} \; -print
```

Read `man find` to learn more.

---

#### EDIT:

This command (mis)uses `avconv`, as you requested:

```
find -exec sh -c 'file --mime-type "$1" | grep -q "video/"' sh {} \; -exec sh -c 'avconv 2>&1 -i "$1" | grep -q "Stream.*x720"' sh {} \; -print
```

The issue is every invocation of `avconv` therein throws an error. We just ignore it and extract the information we need. This is somewhat ugly solution. I'm not entirely sure your `avconv` behaves as mine, you may need to replace `Stream.*x720` with some other regex.

---

> what is wrong in my combined command string?

- `find -exec` requires closing with `\;` or `+`,
- <strike>there is `$(` without `)`</strike> after you edited the question there are `""` interleaved (not nested) with `$()`,
- `*720*` may trigger shell globbing, should be `"*720*"` (I'm talking about `sh`, not the outer shell),
- the output of `avconv` you try to parse goes to `stderr`, I think you need to redirect it before you can parse it,
- and maybe something else.

Comment: you are right: ) is missing. So I corrected to:find -exec sh -c 'if [[ "$(avconv -i {}") == "*720*" ]] ; then echo 720 found; fi;'
')' after {}"  ... but the result of executions seems to read the content of the files themselves.
Note: the stars * are invisible here

Comment: ...the other thing is, I don't have the 'ffprobe' command in my repo, or I don't know the package name (Sabayon)

Comment: @Linuxwhisperer `ffprobe` is in `ffmpeg` in my Kubuntu. Any similar tool should work (you should adjust the `grep` to the tool, of course). The point is you shouldn't use `avconv` for this because it requires the output file, throws an error – at least in (K)Ubuntu.

Comment: @Linuxwhisperer Sabayon is based on Gentoo, isn't it? Then [read this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/82021/108618).

Comment: thank you, but as all I read and know, ffmpeg is more and more substituted by avconv. I have installed virtual/ffmpeg-9-r2 on my system, but ffprobe is not part of it I assume.
Anyway, could you send me a construct build with find or for i ... and grep *720*, pls?

Comment: @ Kamil: yes, Sabayon is Gentoo based but they are binaries... And even after installing pfl, there is no ffprobe...

Comment: I'm so much against provoking an error with the converter only to get a resolution info. Which of [these tools](https://stackoverflow.com/q/684015) can you use?

Comment: @Linuxwhisperer See my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you again, Kamil. I tried your (mis)used avconv command in a find environment. Now I have two oneliners to reach my goal...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know avconv, I usually use ffmpeg.
If you install it you could use this script

```
#!/bin/bash
OIFS="$IFS"
IFS=$'\n'

files=$(find ./ -type f -exec ls {} + | grep ".*\.mpg$\|.*\.avi$\|.*\.mkv$\|.*\.mp4$"| cut -c3-)

for f in ${files}
do
resolution=$(ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries 
stream=height -of csv=s=x:p=0 ${f})
printf "%-100s %-10s\n" $f $resolution
done
```

Answer (score 0):

For the moment I have found a usable solution:

```
 for i in ls *.m??; do sm=$(mediainfo $i | grep Height | sed 's/  //g');if [[ "$sm" == *720* ]]; then printf "Video: %-s $i %-s $sm \n"; fi; done
```

Here I can loop all m?? video files and print its name including "720" condition. Without the if part I could let show me all videos and their resolutions.

I worked this out with the help of other answers here.

When I try to combine find and exec and the do part of the solution above, I only receive "E: File read error" messages as result from mediainfo for each subject:

```
 find -exec mediainfo "{}" \; -exec bash -c 'sm=$(mediainfo ${} | grep 720) : ; echo $sm' \;
```

As I said, the 'if' construction works (for the actual directory), but I will try to make it run with find also.

Comment: Oh, sorry for being talkative. I've read now...