# Use find to delete all images under given dimensions

Tags: bash, data-recovery, find, sorting, image-processing

I just used Recuva and Photorec to recover some data off an accidentally-formatted drive. Naturally, the result is every intact file that ever existed on the drive during its lifetime. This means tens of thousands of small icon images, both PNGs and JPGs, that I would like to delete - let's say anything under 100 x 100px.

There are [solutions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/581784/how-to-remove-image-files-that-are-smaller-than-certain-dimensions) out [there](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96957/delete-all-jpg-in-a-folder-that-are-smaller-than-specific-width-heigth), but they're all fairly complicated and even the most simple rely on piping through several external programs and `rm` to do the actual deleting. This is not ideal because when doing something often enough in `bash` I always prefer a one-liner that I can remember and type out on the command line each time.

In an era of a much more fully-fledged GNU `find` that comes with `-delete`, is there really no way to do this entirely or even mostly within `find` itself?

EDIT: If `find` won't cut it, I would also be happy to use any other GNU tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In an era of a much more fully-fledged GNU `find` that comes with `-delete`, is there really no way to do this entirely or even mostly within `find` itself?

`find` is not for reading image (meta)data (compare ["DOTADIW"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy#Do_One_Thing_and_Do_It_Well)). To perform an arbitrary test, use `-exec` as a test ([example](https://superuser.com/a/1221882/432690)) and then `-delete`. It may be like:

```
find . -type f -exec some_program -with -options -that -test -dimensions {} \; -delete
```

Iff `some_program` returns exit status `0` for a file then `-delete` will kick in for the file.

For more complicated tests you may need an inner shell:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'shell-code "$1" | with-pipes && con-di-tio-nals -and -such' arbitrary-name {} \; -delete
```

Iff `sh` returns exit status `0` then `-delete` will kick in.

One big advantage: [you can do this safely](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156010/108618) even if there are newlines, spaces or special characters in filenames. The code is robust.

One big disadvantage: `-exec … \;` will run one `some_program` *per file*. Or one `sh`, `shell-code`, `with-pipes` and `con-di-tio-nals` per file. Creating an additional process is costly, so this approach may not perform well.

To mitigate the disadvantage you may pass more filenames to the inner shell at once. This is what [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/581792/693277) does (the code has been debugged):

> ```
> find . -iname "*.jpg" -type f -exec bash -c 'for i; do size=($(identify -format "%w %h" "$i")); (( size[0] < 300 || size[1] < 300 )) && rm -v "$i"; done' remove-files {} +
> ```

Note `-exec … +` here is not a test that would trigger `-delete`. Each shell process handles multiple files and returns a single exit status, so it's not a useful test for a single file. Instead, `rm` is conditionally called from within the shell.

Still there will be one `identify` per file and one `rm` per file-to-be-deleted. On the other hand there will be one `bash` per *many files*. For good performance you should strongly prefer shell builtins, shell arithmetic and shell syntax over external executables. This approach still processes filenames safely and firmly.

---

There are tools that can test many files with a single process. Example:

```
exiftool -q -r -if '$ImageHeight < 100' -if '$ImageWidth < 100' -p '$Directory/$FileName' .
```

<sup>(This is `exiftool` from the `libimage-exiftool-perl` package in Debian. Solution taken from [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/52921/108618).)</sup>

Note this particular command is not limited to "PNGs and JPGs".

The command *prints* results like `find . … -print` would. You can then pipe to `xargs` to call `rm`. [Common concerns](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/321753/108618) about piping paths as text apply and I'm not sure one can make `exiftool` act like `find . … -print0`.

So while this solution may perform good when it comes to finding files and printing their paths, it's not the most robust way to actually delete them without human supervision.

Comment: Upvoted and accepted because this pointed me in the right direction, but I've posted a follow-up question here about the solution that I went with: https://superuser.com/questions/1514011/identify-fails-to-match-images-lower-than-given-dimensions.