# Understanding Operators in find command

Tags: linux, bash, unix, shell, find

```
[kony@HOSTNAME testing]$ pwd
/apps/kony/fmw/testing
[kony@HOSTNAME testing]$ touch SCCS
[kony@HOSTNAME testing]$ touch NOT_SCCS
[kony@HOSTNAME testing]$
[kony@HOSTNAME testing]$ find . -name SCCS -prune -o -print
.
./NOT_SCCS
[kony@HOSTNAME testing]$

[kony@HOSTNAME testing]$
```

I am trying to understand how Logical operators work in find and how it affects prune.

1. First Find command .

It will be treated as "`find . -name  SCCS -and -prune -o -print`" .  (An implicity -and between name and -prune action.

For every file and directory in current directory first "-name SCCS" condition will be checked. If name matches SCCS then the condition is true . Since First condition is true and "-and" is mentioned it will check next condition . next condition is "-prune" it will be evalvauted to true . So it will be like
"`find . true -and true -o -print`" which means "`find . true -o -print`" . Since left condition is true and there is -or operation then next condition will be evaluated  which is -print.
This means that it should print file whose name is SCCS . Then why it is not printing. Am i understanding it wrongly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I understanding it wrongly?

You are.

<sub>Note: formally [POSIX `find`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) does not define `true` as an operand. GNU `find` understands `-true` (with a leading dash) and `-false`. I will use these forms. I understand what you mean by `true` though.</sub>

I think you got the logic right up to (and including) `find . -true -o -print`. What you're missing is the fact an expression like `subexpression1 -o subexpression2` or `subexpression1 -a subexpression2` evaluates `subexpression1` first and if its outcome is enough to tell the result of the entire expression then `subexpression2` will *not* be evaluated. This means

```
-true -o -print
```

doesn't evaluate `-print` because sole `-true` is enough to tell the whole snippet evaluates to true. Similarly

```
-false -a -print
```

doesn't evaluate `-print` because sole `-false` is enough to tell the whole snippet evaluates to false.

The latter behavior is quite intuitive. E.g. with `find . -name foo -print` you don't want `find` to `-print` when `-name foo` is false. Realize it's a direct result of the general rule where `subexpression1 -a subexpression2` does not evaluate `subexpression2` if it's not necessary. Do not perceive `find` only as a tool to find or to print something. Think of it as of a tool to *evaluate the given expression*. Then it will be easy (or at least easier) to understand the behavior of `-true -o -print` and to treat `-exec` as a custom test (which is awesome, you can test virtually anything; [example](https://superuser.com/a/1221882/432690)).

I have written one [quite comprehensive answer](https://superuser.com/a/1577902/432690) about how `find` works. Unfortunately it's under a question that got little attention, so the answer itself got little attention too. But maybe you will find it useful.